# Are there any good examples of Jira configured for small software team

Tags: jira

Jira or Jira Studio are wonderful products and heavy customization is definitely one of their strongest sides, but it also means that all those customization options are a bit overwhelming.

Are there any good resources (open or demo Jira instances, articles, videos etc) that will demonstrate a good Jira setup for small product-oriented software company.

Answer (score 5):

Did you look at the *Atlassian Dragon Quest* - a configuration scenario for setting up the complete Atlassian tool stack: [Here Be Dragons](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ATLAS/Here+Be+Dragons)

Would this meet your requirements?

Comment: this is nice but unfortunately it doesn't really show how to handle support or professional services (implementations). Do you have something that would be usable for a whole small organization end-to-end preferably using kanban

Comment: Atlassian recently released the workflow sharing plugin and a bunch of precooked workflows.  There is an ITIL specific workflow config - check https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.workflow.bundles.itil  but there are many more.

Comment: We're on OnDemand. It's my understanding we can't get plugins installed. We ended up configuring separate projects for each implementation project, one for support, and one for development. Issues in support get escalated by assigning to dev manager then he links them to a new dev issue and prioritizes it on our greenhopper backlog. When we're done the dev manager (PO) marks the support issue 'fixed'.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a specialized 'small business' configuration for JIRA. As long as the default configuration works well with your workflows, I might just use it as it is.

I would call it a big advantage, getting a preconfigured issue tracking system  out of the box. Further configuration can be done step by step, keeping your users on board.

Answer (score 0):

A number of open source projects use Jira under their free OSS licence. You might check out Apache's set of projects, for example:

https://issues.apache.org/

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Instant Atlassian](http://blogs.atlassian.com/developer/2009/04/setting_up_jira_and_confluence.html) to easily install & host Jira and Confluence on Amazon EC2. The licenses for small teams (10 people) are $5 each, and the running costs with Amazon are $5-10 per month.